# Is there a way to use external file for multiple importMappings in POM?

Tags: maven, openapi-generator

I am using openapi generator maven plugin to generate some core DTOs which are used in multiple modules. If I want to use them in next generated module I simply put into importMapping the import package so the new module won't generate the same DTO but use the core generated DTO. I have like 30 of them and don't want to type all of them into POM which generates everything in multiple executions. Can I somehow use some external file which I can pass into importMappings? Or is there some better way to do it.

So I don't have to type:

```
<importMappings>
  <importMapping>User=cz.packages.core.UserDTO</importMapping>
  <importMapping>SomeObject=cz.packages.core.SomeObjectDTO</importMapping>
  <importMapping>SomeObject2=cz.packages.core.SomeObject2DTO</importMapping> ...
</importMappings>
```

in every execution in pom

Comment: Hi & welcome to [SO]! As understanding your question, the "most maven" way to do *this* would be: to introduce/generate/install/deploy "an artifact" (group:artifact:version:type... containing your (compiled, tested, documented...) dtos), which can be used by other projects (as dependency) ..with all of its contents! (Post some code/config !;)

Comment: If you generate them you are building jar files of them...if you deploy them or use them within a multi module build you can reuse them? Please explain more in detail what you do etc.

Comment: I am using openapi generator to generate package of core DTO and package of enums. In next execution I am creating module with apis and their own module-specific DTOs. But openapi will generate duplicate DTO instead of using already generated in core package. To use them I can type into configuration of that execution in importmappings to import already generated class but I have lot of them and I would have to type for every single DTO into importMappings on several places. So if openapi have better way or if maven can take external file and pass it like list of configurations.

Comment: i am not sure about the capabilities of openapi-plugin, but with this approach: you have to maintain that list/mapping (at least) once! a "nice maven" (unique) place for this would be the `pluginManagment` of a parent pom (inherited by all "generating"/using poms). (+ the classes not manually copied, but from "maven artifact";)